# Springframework StandardServletEnvironment Initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I look at the logs of my spring web application with debug log level enabled, I find the following log messages repeatedly in the log output:

```
2016-08-11 13:36:46 DEBUG --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] or.sp.we.co.su.StandardServletEnvironment          : Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-08-11 13:36:46 DEBUG --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] or.sp.we.co.su.StandardServletEnvironment          : Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-08-11 13:36:46 DEBUG --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] or.sp.we.co.su.StandardServletEnvironment          : Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-08-11 13:36:46 DEBUG --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] or.sp.we.co.su.StandardServletEnvironment          : Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-08-11 13:36:46 DEBUG --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] or.sp.we.co.su.StandardServletEnvironment          : Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-08-11 13:36:46 DEBUG --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] or.sp.we.co.su.StandardServletEnvironment          : Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
```

In a single application start this happens about 17 times. I am wondering why it is necessary to initialize the property sources so many times and why Spring is not caching that somewhere internally. Would it not be enough to initialize the `StandardServletEnvironment` one time and use it as a singleton in the application?

I am wondering if this is standard spring behavior or if this happens due to some non optimal configuration in my application?

Comment: It's exactly the same happened to my application. I think it is the bootstrap process loading the external properties.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but the question is, why does the bootstrap process need to do that 17 times for each application start?

Comment: are you creating lot of new spring contexts?